# Build failed for libadwaita-1 while installing easyeffects

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, dell, compiling

### Background

Trying to install easyeffects on ubuntu-20.04 following steps in mentioned here https://github.com/wwmm/easyeffects/wiki/Installation-from-Source. libadwaita-1 dependency not found error popped up on
`meson _build --prefix=/usr command`
The following is the log.

```
The Meson build system
Version: 0.60.3
Source dir: /home/mylinux/Downloads/easyeffects
Build dir: /home/mylinux/Downloads/easyeffects/_build
Build type: native build
Project name: easyeffects
Project version: 6.2.1
C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 9.3.0 "cc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0")
C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.34
C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 9.3.0 "c++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0")
C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.34
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Configuring config.h using configuration
Program appstream-util found: NO
Program desktop-file-validate found: YES (/usr/bin/desktop-file-validate)
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.1)
Program glib-compile-resources found: YES (/usr/bin/glib-compile-resources)
Configuring com.github.wwmm.easyeffects.service using configuration
Program itstool found: YES (/usr/bin/itstool)
Library zita-convolver found: YES
Library tbb found: YES
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.1)
Run-time dependency libpipewire-0.3 found: YES 0.3.42
Run-time dependency glib-2.0 found: YES 2.71.0
Run-time dependency gtk4 found: YES 4.6.0
Found CMake: /usr/local/bin/cmake (3.22.1)
Run-time dependency libadwaita-1 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)

src/meson.build:121:0: ERROR: Dependency "libadwaita-1" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake
```

### Installation failed for libadwaita-1

Followed the installation procedure in [this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libadwaita) link for libadwaita-1 after cloning the repository. Got the error on `ninja -C _build`. Following is the error log.

```
ninja: Entering directory `_build'
[4/44] Generating src/libadwaita-1.vapi with a custom command
FAILED: src/libadwaita-1.vapi 
/usr/bin/vapigen --quiet --library=libadwaita-1 --directory=/home/mylinux/Downloads/libadwaita/_build/src --metadatadir=/home/mylinux/Downloads/libadwaita/src --pkg=gio-2.0 --pkg=gtk4 --metadatadir=/home/mylinux/Downloads/libadwaita/src /home/mylinux/Downloads/libadwaita/_build/src/Adw-1.gir
Adw-1.gir:63.7-63.35: error: Adw.ActionRow: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Adw.PreferencesRow' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:1165.7-1165.35: error: Adw.ApplicationWindow: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.ApplicationWindow' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:1314.7-1314.35: error: Adw.Avatar: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:1731.7-1731.35: error: Adw.Bin: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:1874.7-1874.35: error: Adw.ButtonContent: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:2216.7-2216.35: error: Adw.Carousel: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:3001.7-3001.35: error: Adw.CarouselIndicatorDots: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:3128.7-3128.35: error: Adw.CarouselIndicatorLines: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:3288.7-3288.35: error: Adw.Clamp: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:3732.7-3732.35: error: Adw.ClampScrollable: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:4085.69-4085.69: error: The type name `Gtk.Expression' could not be found
Adw-1.gir:4108.89-4108.89: error: The type name `Gtk.ListItemFactory' could not be found
Adw-1.gir:4131.89-4131.89: error: The type name `Gtk.ListItemFactory' could not be found
Adw-1.gir:4262.71-4262.71: error: The type name `Gtk.Expression' could not be found
Adw-1.gir:4291.91-4291.91: error: The type name `Gtk.ListItemFactory' could not be found
Adw-1.gir:4320.91-4320.91: error: The type name `Gtk.ListItemFactory' could not be found
Adw-1.gir:4422.38-4422.38: error: The type name `Gtk.Expression' could not be found
Adw-1.gir:4422.38-4422.38: error: The type name `Gtk.Expression' could not be found
Adw-1.gir:4422.38-4422.38: error: The type name `Gtk.Expression' could not be found
Adw-1.gir:4438.48-4438.48: error: The type name `Gtk.ListItemFactory' could not be found
Adw-1.gir:4438.48-4438.48: error: The type name `Gtk.ListItemFactory' could not be found
Adw-1.gir:4438.48-4438.48: error: The type name `Gtk.ListItemFactory' could not be found
Adw-1.gir:4453.48-4453.48: error: The type name `Gtk.ListItemFactory' could not be found
Adw-1.gir:4453.48-4453.48: error: The type name `Gtk.ListItemFactory' could not be found
Adw-1.gir:4453.48-4453.48: error: The type name `Gtk.ListItemFactory' could not be found
Adw-1.gir:4057.7-4057.35: error: Adw.ComboRow: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Adw.ActionRow' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:5101.7-5101.35: error: Adw.ExpanderRow: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Adw.PreferencesRow' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:5616.7-5616.35: error: Adw.Flap: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:6806.7-6806.35: error: Adw.HeaderBar: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:7313.7-7313.35: error: Adw.Leaflet: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:8719.7-8719.35: error: Adw.PreferencesGroup: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:8961.7-8961.35: error: Adw.PreferencesPage: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:9320.7-9320.35: error: Adw.PreferencesRow: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.ListBoxRow' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:9507.7-9507.35: error: Adw.PreferencesWindow: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Adw.Window' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:9959.7-9959.35: error: Adw.SplitButton: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:11373.7-11373.35: error: Adw.Squeezer: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:12293.7-12293.35: error: Adw.StatusPage: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:13903.7-13903.35: error: Adw.TabBar: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:15149.7-15149.35: error: Adw.TabView: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:17725.7-17725.35: error: Adw.ToastOverlay: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:17950.7-17950.35: error: Adw.ViewStack: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:19011.7-19011.35: error: Adw.ViewSwitcher: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:19220.7-19220.35: error: Adw.ViewSwitcherBar: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:19475.7-19475.35: error: Adw.ViewSwitcherTitle: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:19849.7-19849.35: error: Adw.Window: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Window' and `Gtk.Accessible')
Adw-1.gir:19975.7-19975.35: error: Adw.WindowTitle: Classes cannot have multiple base classes (`Gtk.Widget' and `Gtk.Accessible')
[9/44] Compiling C object tests/test-preferences-group.p/test-preferences-group.c.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

### Needed Fix

can I install easyeffects without needing libadwaita or how to install libadwaita and continue installing easyeffects or any better apps available for better audio enhancements for ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

libadwaita is not available for Ubuntu 20.04. You can install Ubuntu 21.10 and follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385690/how-to-satisfy-libadwaita-1-build-dependency-in-gnome-meson) answer to get libadwaita. It will be available in the official repositories of Ubuntu 22.04 (to be released in April 2022) onward.

However, you can easily install easyeffects in Ubuntu 20.04 [with flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.wwmm.easyeffects), with the following commands.

```
sudo apt install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub com.github.wwmm.easyeffects
```

Comment: Installed easyeffects with the above commands. After opening easyeffects it is plain. easyeffects is not detecting any players and none of the options are enabled.

Comment: Find the github project of the software and open an issue there.

Comment: Installed [PulseEffects](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/06/install-audio-effects-pulseeffects-ubuntu-18-04-higher/) as an alternative and it works good. Audio noise issue was solved by following the instructions in the [link](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-hissing-noise-over-headphones-only-in-ubuntu/) and restarting the system.